# How to show loader when ionic selectable opens

Tags: ionic3

How can I show a loading modal before the list of ionic-selectable opens? My current approach is the following:

```
<ionic-selectable [(ngModel)]="control" [items]="freeSupplyIteme1" itemValueField="product_id"
                itemTextField="description" placeholder="select product" [canSearch]="true"
                (onChange)="portChange($event,i)">
</ionic-selectable>
```

I want to open the loader when clicked on ionic selectable and close the loader when data is displayed in the ionic selectable list.